# Drawing cryptographic algorithms with Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

currently I am working on some cryptographic stuff and I need to draw some drawings with Visio. There is the need to draw symmetric cryptopgrahic algorithms. My problem is to draw a permutation like this:

[image]

I tried to to some short lines in the top and bottom of the page and then draw the connection between the two lines. I can not connect multiple connectors to each other.

In the end it should look like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the the connectors are missing connection points where you want
to do the connection, such points can be added to any shape.

This is the procedure for shapes (I don't know if it applies to connectors),
from the article
[Edit connector lines, arrows, or points](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-connector-lines-arrows-or-points-5669491f-9fce-4676-81f8-ef4553788416),
section *Add a connection point to a shape*:

> 1. Select the shape.
> 2. On the Home tab, in the Tools group, click the Connection Point tool Button [image] .
> 3. If connection points are not visible, on the View tab, in the Visual Aids group, select the Connection Points check box.
> 4. Press Ctrl and click where you want to add a connection point. The new connection point is automatically selected after you place it.
> 5. On the Home tab, in the Tools group, click Pointer Tool Select Objects to return to normal editing.